# String SQL snippet conditions on translated attributes are not forming proper query, whereas hash syntax of the same query works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, globalize

Rails verison : 4.2.7.1
Globalize version: 5.0.1

Example:

```
class User
  translates name
end
```

`User.where("name=?", "ABC")` is not working

query generated:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (name='Self')
```

where as,
`User.where(name: "ABC")` is working fine.

query generated:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_translations` ON `user_translations`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE `user_translations`.`name` = 'Self' AND `user_translations`.`locale` = 'en'
```

Comment: whats the query generated by both the approaches

Comment: @deepak I have updated my question